# Update: Include house ownership and house cost in a model

Tags: regression, ordered-logit

I would like to include house ownership (binary, 0 no, 1 yes) and property cost (continuous, logged) in an ordinal logistic model. 
If a respondent does not own the house where he/she lives, the value of property cost would be 0.

My question is whether it is appropriate to include both variables in the model.

I am interested to know:

1. the chance that the outcome variable is found in a higher instead of lower category increases by Y per cent if the respondents own the house.
2. the chance that the outcome variable is found in a higher instead of lower category increases by Y per cent as the property cost increases by X per cent.

My concern is that these two variables kind of depend on each other.

**Update 1**

When the models add both the house ownership and property cost as explanatory variables, I expect that both variables' signs are positive. However, for all four outcome variables, the effect of property cost is positive, as expected; but the effect of binary house ownership (1 yes 0 no) is negative. For some outcome variables, the house ownership is negative and statistically significant.

When the models uses only either house ownership and property cost but not both, the variable's sign is positive.

These results make me wonder if something wrong is going on with using two variables together.

**Update 2**

I compared BIC and AIC but found out using one or two variables do not make substantial differences. Only for one outcome variable, the BIC difference is higher than 10.

I used only the house ownership variable in my first draft, but reviewers asked for house price. I intended to use both variables. But it seems that I may need to drop house ownership and set the house cost as zero for people who do not own a house.

Comment: You've answered your own question by showing that you realise that you need to tread carefully. But quite what is a good model for your data is not something we can guess at easily. In practice, unless the predictors are essentially identical (and clearly they aren't) including both in the model is fine so long as you realise that the predictors act as a team and that estimates depend inevitably on what else is in the mode.

Comment: an easy solution is not to set the cost to zero if the guy doesn't own a house

Comment: @Aksakal If the cost is coded as missing for the respondent who does not own the house, the model would omit the binary house ownership.

Comment: @Minn, no missing would not help at all, it would be ["missing not at random"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data#Missing_not_at_random), a terrible kind of missing variable. I thought the cost would be available regardless of ownership

Comment: You could simply try out both models (with and without the two variables) and, based on the goodness-of-fit, choose the model that fits the data best. E.g. you could select the model that yields the lowest AIC / Scaled Deviance while at the same time maintains significant p-values in the Likelihood Ratio Test, model coefficients, test of parallel lines, etc.

Comment: Fully agree with @NickCox. Maybe it is worth mentioning that your coding is equivalent to use a dummy (owner 0/1) and the log cost times that dummy. So it is like using an interaction where one slope is forced to be 0.

Comment: Minn, if you're looking for a practical solution to your problem you must try fitting all models that were suggested to you and decide a posteriori.

Comment: @Digio Thank you. I tested the BIC and AIC and updated my question. BIC & AIC do not show strong preferences. But reviewers required to add house cost.

Comment: @Aksakal I updated my questions after a few tests. I am not still sure what you mean by the cost would be available regardless of ownership in practice.

Comment: @MichaelM Thank you. I understood what you mean. But I could not make sense with the variable signs. please see the update.

Comment: @Minn: A negative shift for house owners is not necessarily strange because you are using non-centered log cost as "interacting" variable. So the dummy tries to compensate for the jump between a house with log cost of 0 and the log cost of a small house. Just plot the regression line for house owners and the constant line for non-owners to visualize the result.

Comment: Doesn't property have a cost regardless of who owns it? I might be missing the semantics of property cost variable. In real estate modeling you have the property cost as a separate variable which characeterizes the property, e.g. sale price or appraisal. It seems you have a different meaning for the variable

Comment: @Aksakal Sorry for the confusion. No, the property price refers to "How much did you pay for the property", thus this variable is only available for people who own the house, not for renters.

Comment: That's the problem with that variable. Whether you set it to zero (wrong) or MISSING (correct) is not important. What's important that it is missing not at random. It creates a serious issue. Setting it to zero only hides the issue, but doesn't address it.

Comment: I agree with your comments. I decided to create a quartile variable for house cost for house owner. This variable would be zero for renters. The category of renters would be used as the base level in the models. This solution is not ideal, but it does solve my problem. I still wonder why the house ownership was negative.